# Should I feed my cat whenever she asks?

Tags: cats, diet, feeding

My cat has always been good about weight. She's always been fit, incredibly active, and agile. People often guess she's like 2 but she's actually almost 9 years old. She was indoor for the first year of her life, then transitioned to indoor/out for about 3 years, and has been strictly indoor for the past 4 years.

She just went to the vet a month ago and got weighed at 8.08 which is fine because she's a very small framed cat (like 75% the size of a normal cat I'd say).

But in the last 2 months I've noticed she asks for food a lot more. It's been the same food for almost 2 years so I don't think it's that. She doesn't have worms and the vet said she's very healthy, especially for her age (8 years, 9 in May).

Has anyone else experienced this? Is my cat secretly playing hard while I"m not home and chilling and eating while I am here?

Comment: Welcome to Pets.StackExchange! Your question has been marked as a duplicate of another question. The answers there should help you! If they don't, please come back and edit your question to explain how it is different from that one :)